# Undesired data truncation when updating a MEDIUMBLOB

Tags: php, blob, mariadb, truncation

I'm trying to write in a BLOB in my MariaDB using a PHP post call. This BLOB comes from getting a BASE64 from a canvas:

```
var data= $('#signatureDiv').signature('toDataURL');
var base64data= data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

$.post("myFunc.php", {imgContents: base64data}, function(data) {});
```

Now, in myFunc.php:

```
$imgContents = $_POST['imgContents'];
$decodedPNG = base64_decode($imgContents);

$defTest = "UPDATE recogidas SET FirmaProv = ':blobFirma' WHERE ID=$index";
$preparedpdo = $mypdoObject->prepare($defTest);
$preparedpdo->bindParam(':blobFirma', $decodedPNG, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$preparedpdo->execute();
echo $decodedPNG;
```

I decode the PNG to save it as a BLOB. Then I prepare a SQL update to upload this BLOB to a proper MEDIUMBLOB column. However, the data is always truncated to few bytes!! Exactly to those bytes:

```
3A626C6F624669726D61
```

When it, as a PNG, needs around 100Kb. I tried using this at the beggining of the PHP:

```
ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "1000K");
```

But it has no effect. To make sure the decode was right, I tried to echo the decoded BLOB, and it returns if correctly.

Why is my database truncating the data to a pack of bytes?

Extra information: It doesn't matter how the picture I make in the canvas is, the data uploaded to the data base is always those same characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my database truncating the data to a pack of bytes?

It isn’t. If you had bothered to check what those hex bytes `3A626C6F624669726D61` actually mean, you would have seen that it is `:blobFirma`. And since you instructed the database to store that *string value* in your statement, this is absolutely the result that is to be expected.

If you don’t want to store a fixed string value into the column - then remove the *quotes* around the placeholder from the statement …